# Printing command line args (java program) when using docker run

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-run

I have a java program which prints command line arguments

```
 public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
     }
   }
```

And I have a Docker file as below

```
FROM openjdk:8  
COPY . /src/java
WORKDIR /src/java  
RUN ["javac", "Sample.java"]  
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "Sample"]
```

I have built a docker image for the above program and used below command to run the docker image

```
docker run <image-name> hello world
```

When I run above command expected output is

```
Hello
world
```

but I'm getting an error as below.
[image]
Please, let me know my mistake.
I'm new to docker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: When I run it (Ubuntu host), it works as it should.

Comment: I m running it on Windows machine
and updated the error please check.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show should create a PNG file; what generated the image you attached?  (Did you mean to include text-form logs instead?)  How are you building and running the image (what are the exact `docker build` and `docker run` commands)?

Comment: I used "docker build -t <image-name> . " to build docker image and "docker run <image-name> arg1 arg2" used this to run the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build command to be used is

```
docker build -t my-app:1.0 .
```

Docker run command with args is

```
docker run my-app:1.0 "Hello" "World"
```